# image alignment not properly set to the top right corner

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to set an `icon` on the top right corner of a card but I am not able to align everything.

It should look like this:

[image]

but it looks like:

[image]

```
<Card style={{ width: '16rem', border: 'none', margin: '10px', borderRadius: '20px'}}>
                        <div>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={Dj} className="img-card img-card-small" />
                            <div className="blue-circle-icon">
                                <img src={LiveIcon}
                                    alt="live-icon"
                                    className="icon-tag"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Card.Body style={{borderRadius: '20px'}}>
                            <Card.Text style={{fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro', 
                                    fontSize: '14px', 
                                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                                    fontStretch: 'normal',
                                    fontStyle: 'normal',
                                    lineHeight: '1.6',
                                    letterSpacing: 'normal',
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    color: '#616161'}}>
                            Anyone can apply to earn money by hosting a live-streaming or in-person experience                            
                            </Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
```

and the css is :

```
.img-card {
    object-fit: contain;
    border-radius: 20px;

}

.blue-circle-icon {
    background-color: #14cff0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.icon-tag {
    height: 20px;
    width: auto;

}
```

So if someone know how to make sure that the `white icon` is always centered in the `blue circle`, how to get the `blue circle` always on the top-right corner of the image... I would be happy to have some inputs.

Also, I tried to apply a border radius all around the image but I can't it's weird.. it's only doing it in the bottom

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. white icon is always centered in the blue circle:

add `position: relative;` to `.blue-circle-icon` class and add following css to `.icon-tag`

```
.icon-tag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

2. Similarly to get the blue circle always on the top-right corner of the image:

add `position: relative;` to parent `div` of `.blue-circle-icon` and `.img-card`  and following css to `.blue-circle-icon`

```
.blue-circle-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;    <= adjust these as per your need
  right: -20px;  <= adjust these as per your need
}
```

but here the icon will be positioned in respect to parent `div`, if it possible to put `.blue-circle-icon` inside the `.img-card` as a child then give `.img-card` the `position: relative;` to make sure the icon is always positioned in respect to the card.